# Can pylibmc perform create, put and get cache operations in apache ignite?

Tags: python, ignite

In my application, multiple systems are going to do put and get operations and hence, database locks may be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignite is Memcached compliant which enables users to store and retrieve distributed data from Ignite cache using any Memcached compatible client.

For example you can use pylibmc (Python client for memcached) as described here:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.4/docs/memcached-support#python

Comment: Thanks but does Memcached support building multiple cache? There does not seem to any option to specify the cache name in pylibmc.

Comment: Looks like it's not supported. ODBC connections is better variant for multiple caches.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite supports ODBC connections. You can build an ODBC driver for your system and use `pyodbc` library to execute SQL queries in Apache Ignite.

Here is documentation on building Ignite ODBC driver: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/odbc-driver#building-odbc-driver

Here is an example of how to connect to Ignite over ODBC from Python:

```python
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER='Apache Ignite', ADDRESS='localhost', SCHEMA='PUBLIC', autocommit=True)

cnxn.execute('select * from Person')
```